# How do I redirect IntelliJ's config path?

Tags: intellij-idea

Installed IntelliJ, but when I try to open it, it says:
 `Config path '/Users/xxx/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea12 is invalid. If you have modified the idea.config.path property, please make sure it is correct, otherwise please reinstall the IDE`.

I tried reinstalling to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is answered in the [IDE FAQ document](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23348963).

On Mac `idea.properties` file doesn't define these options by default.
You can try adding them manually.

To diagnose the problem do the following in the Terminal:

```
cd /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ 12.app/Contents/MacOS/
export IDEA_LAUNCHER_DEBUG=1
./idea
```

Provide the debug output. It will help to understand where the IDE may be taking incorrect properties from.

Comment: I did find the idea.properties file in the bin folder, but it doesn't have these options :/


        idea.config.path

        idea.system.path...

I'm on mac btw.

Comment: the first 2 lines are:
idea.popup.weight=heavy
idea.dynamic.classpath=false

Comment: and it goes on like that for a few lines, ends with: 
    sun.java2d.d3d=false
    apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true.

Comment: I executed ./idea on terminal, IntelliJ successfully launches, the terminal gives errors like `: 2013-06-17 15:32:01.121 idea[527:1903] Reading at /Users/sgupta/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea12/idea.vmoptions failed, Error is: The file “idea.vmoptions” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file` AND `[   4781]   WARN - j.ui.mac.MacMainFrameDecorator - no url bundle present`

Comment: This error is harmless, it means that default `idea.vmoptions` is used.

Comment: Hmm. There's also `Reading at /Users/sgupta/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea12/idea.properties failed, Error is: The file “idea.properties” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.` AND `WARN - pl.ExternalResourceManagerImpl - Cannot find standard resource. filename:/META-INF/tapestry_5_0_0.xsd class=null `

Comment: It's also OK, default `idea.properties` is used.

Comment: Note that it's not recommended to modify the original `idea.properties` file, you should copy it to `/Users/sgupta/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea12/idea.properties` and modify the copy instead. If you modify the original file, application digital signature will be violated and you may get firewall warnings, warnings when trying to access the keystore, etc.